# Javascript guess number game not working

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I am creating a simple game where the program generates a random number between 1-1000 and then the user inputs a number. If it is smaller it generates too low if it is larger it generates too high and congratulations if it is correct. The problem is my program always generates too high.Can you  help me? Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var numri=gjenero();
    function gjenero(){
        return Math.floor(1000*Math.random())+1;
    }
    function kontrollo(){
     pergjigja=parseInt(document.getElementById("pergjigja").value);
        if (numri<pergjigja){
           alert("Too low!");
           document.getElementById("pergjigja").value="";

        }
        else if (numri>pergjigja){
            alert("Too high!");
            document.getElementById("pergjigja").value="";
        }
        else {
             alert("Congratulations.Continue the game with another 
        number!");
            gjenero();
        }
    }
   </script>
    </head>
       <body>

   <input type="text" id="pergjigja" >
   <button onclick="kontrollo();">Check</button>
  </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: "_my program always generates too high_" I ran the code and this did not happen. The random number was 157, I entered 200, it said "too low". (As a side note, the messages seem backwards to me - I would think the message is telling me my number is too low but it was the reverse)

Comment: Note that at the end of the function, you're generating a new number without assigning it to the variable.  Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle of a working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/9jmt7anj/10/

Answer (score 1):

You have your logic backwards:

`numri` is the random number, and `pergjigja` is the input. If you type in `1001`, then you'll see the *Too low* error message.

You should update the `<` and `>` operators like so to have the desired behavior:

```
if (numri>pergjigja){
   alert("Too low!");
   document.getElementById("pergjigja").value="";

}
else if (numri<pergjigja){
    alert("Too high!");
    document.getElementById("pergjigja").value="";
}
else {
    alert("Congratulations.Continue the game with another number!");
    numri=gjenero();
}
```